# Custom Dropdown Button and MenuItems Flutter

Tags: flutter, drop-down-menu, menuitem

I am trying to build my own drop down button with separated and condensed menu items, like the image below:

[image: Source inspiration]

here's the code I have tried so far, I got the drop down width to match the container but the items can't be customized so far and always the height starts from above the button and is not occupying the width of the container:

```
body: Container(
    margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0, vertical: 5.0),
    child: Container(
      width: double.infinity,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10.0)),
          border: Border.all(color: Colors.brown, width: 1.0)),
      padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10.0, 5.0, 10.0, 5.0),
      child: DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
        child: ButtonTheme(
          alignedDropdown: true,
          child: DropdownButton(
            isExpanded: true,
            isDense: true,
            value: selection,
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.arrow_drop_down,
              color: Colors.brown,
            ),
            iconSize: 40,
            underline: Container(
              height: 1,
              color: Colors.transparent,
            ),
            onChanged: (String val) => setState(() => selection = val),
            items: settingsOptions.map((option) {
              return DropdownMenuItem(
                value: option,
                child: Text(option),
              );
            }).toList(),
          ),
        ),
      )
    ),
  ),
```

This is the output from the code:
[image: Different Output]

How do I customize the items width, height and add dividers like in the first image? Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an example modify as you like !

```
DropdownButton(
        isExpanded: true,
        isDense: true,
        value: selection,
        icon: Icon(
          Icons.arrow_drop_down,
          color: Colors.brown,
        ),
        iconSize: 40,
        underline: Container(
          height: 1,
          color: Colors.transparent,
        ),
        onChanged: (String val) => setState(() => selection = val),
        items: sampleList.map((option) {
          return DropdownMenuItem(
            value: option,
            child: Container(
              width:double.infinity,
              alignment:Alignment.centerLeft,
              padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0,8.0,0,6.0),
              child:Text(option),
              decoration:BoxDecoration(
              border:Border(top:BorderSide(color:Colors.grey,width:1))
              )
            ),
          );
        }).toList(),
        selectedItemBuilder:(con){
              return sampleList.map((m){
                return Text(m,);
              }).toList();
            }
      )
```

[image: pic]

Comment: RenderBox error due to DropdownMenuItem's Container child having double.infinity width, but once this is commented out, the first open has the items height under the appbar but subsequently, it defaults back to second image in question.

Comment: I have accepted your answer, but please consider updating it sir. Thank you so much.

Comment: I tested it with dartpad ! Can you pls add where exactly error occurred !?

Comment: I removed the container width, it works but not like in image. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Yes, nothing changed

Comment: Oh ok, if the dropdown buttons are less then use alertdialog with a flat/raised button !

Comment: Can you show an example? Will the dialog not cover other content or have some elevation?

Answer (score 0):

I came across a flutter Library called dropdown_below in pub.dev. It has additional methods that can allow you customize dropdownMenuItem to your preferred layout.

```
DropdownBelow(
                    value: category,
                    // isDense: true,
                    itemWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.92,
                    itemTextstyle: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 14,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                        color: Colors.black),
                    boxTextstyle: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 14,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                        color: Colors.grey.shade600),
                    boxPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(13, 12, 0, 12),
                    boxWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                    boxHeight: 60,
                    hint: Text('choose video'),
                    items: video.data.value.videos
                        .map((e) => DropdownMenuItem(
                              onTap: () => e.title,
                              value: e.title ?? category,
                              child: Container(
                                width: double.infinity,
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(),
                                child: Padding(
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                  child: Text(
                                    e.title ?? '$category',
                                    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ))
                        .toList(),
                    onChanged: (video) {
                      context.read(videoProvider).cateroryOnChange(video);
                    },
                  ),
```

Library Link: https://pub.dev/packages/dropdown_below

Comment: providing a link and some exmple code would be very helpful

Comment: Thank you sir. I'll check it out

Answer (score 0):

[image]

The problem with the DropdownButton is that the menu will open randomly based on the selected index and other things. Also, You can't edit its code by just trying to pass offset as the logic code of the paint work based on that and trying to hardcode the selectedItemOffset to a value won't work perfectly fine.

So use DropDownButton2 , which is built just over this .

Package: [DropDownButton2](https://pub.dev/packages/dropdown_button2)

Credits: [Ahmed Elsayed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70184781/13431819)

For reference: [Refer this link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59859034/13431819)