# how to add margin in dropdown item menu

Tags: flutter, dart

how to add margin in dropdown item menu? i want to add space in every menu item

here is my code

```
// Dropdown Box
        Container(
         .....
          child: DropdownButton(
            elevation: 1,
            isExpanded: true,
            hint: Text(
              '--Select One--',
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Color(0xffB2B2B2),
              ),
            ),
           
            items: dropdownOption.map((e) {
              return DropdownMenuItem(
                value: e['value'],
                child: Text(e['label']),
              );
            }).toList(),
            value: dropdownValue,
            onChanged: (value) {
              setState(() {
                dropdownValue = value;
              });

            },
          ),
        ),
```

[image]

if i put padding in text dropdown menu it looks like this

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Custom Dropdown Button and MenuItems Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59715001/custom-dropdown-button-and-menuitems-flutter)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it turns out it's really simple just add `itemHeight` in `DropdownButton` lol

example:

```
DropdownButton(
              itemHeight: 70,
),
```

Answer (score 1):

By simply wrapping your `text` widget with `padding` widget.

Comment: the menu gone overlapped, i updated the question

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with [DropdownButton2](https://pub.dev/packages/dropdown_button2) by using `itemPadding` property. DropdownButton2 is based on Flutter's core DropdownButton with steady dropdown menu below the button and many other options you can customize to your needs.

**Disclaimer:** I am the author of the package mentioned above.